# Input multiple strings on different line into arrays or lists based on the number of lines in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, input

Eg. Suppose 
4 - no of workers
w is worker , s is skill 
Input :

```
4
w1#s1
w2#s2
w3#s3
w4#s1
```

---

I've tried

```
n = int(input())
array = dict()
for i in range(n):
    array['array_'+ str(i)]= list(map(lambda y : input("), [y for  y in range(5)]))                      # range 5 as 5 is a fixed 5 line input
```

Basically , our aim is to get those input string into separate array or list based on no of workers,  but I don't know my no of workers before hand  , so how do I loop multiple arrays as input  and I also want individual arrays indexed because I have to perform further operations on it .

Comment: @Ch3steR  , I've edited and put the code I tried

Answer (score 0):

Here as you didn't know how many times you want to take input ,just add a try except clock to check if input is ended or not. Whenever you take input as a blank line , python gives EOF Exception

```
a=[]
b=[]
while True: 
 try: 
  s=input ()
  data=s.split("#")
  a.append(data[0])
  b.append(data[1])      
 except EOFERROR:
  break
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.